# How to perform cumulative_sum in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cumsum

Hi I have a sample dataframe as follows:

| group 1 | group 2 | cond 1 | point | total_capacity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 0 | 0.3 | 2 |
| A | 1 | 1 | 0.5 | 2 |
| A | 1 | 0 | 0.8 | 2 |
| A | 1 | 0 | 0.2 | 2 |
| A | 1 | 0 | 0.4 | 2 |
| B | 2 | 0 | 0.6 | 4 |
| B | 2 | 0 | 0.3 | 4 |
| B | 2 | 1 | 0.1 | 4 |
| B | 2 | 0 | 0.4 | 4 |
| B | 3 | 0 | 0.5 | 4 |
| B | 3 | 0 | 0.2 | 4 |

I am trying to create another column with values of 0 and 1 based on few conditions.
with in each group of group 1 and group 2 whenever the cond 1 = 1, i am suming all the remaining rows of point within each group and I check whether the total sum of point is less than or equal to total_capacity.

I tried the follwoing code,

```
df['new_col'] = 0

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['cond_1'] == 1:
        group_1 = row['group_1']
        group_2 = row['group_2']
        total_capacity = row['total_capacity']
        point = row['point']
        
        remaining_point = df[(df['group_1'] == group_1) & (df['group_2'] == group_1) & (df.index >= index)]['point'].sum()
        remaining_cap = remaining_point / 1.1
     
        if (remaining_cap < total_capacity):
            combined_df.at[index, 'new_col'] = 1
```

However, I also need to calculate cumulative sum of point column and reset to 0 once it reaches 1.1. and i need to check whether the reset count <= total_capacity. I am not sure how to include this condition in the above code. As per my logic, the new_col will be 1 in the first group combination beacuse (0.5 + 0.8 + 0.2 + 0.4) / 1.1 <= 2. But when we include the cumulative sum and the reset count, new_col will 0, because 0.5 + 0.8 is 1.3, so 0.5 = reset_count = 1, 0.8+0.2 = 1, reset_count =2 and 0.4 reset_count =3, finally, the condition reset_count 3 < 2 is not true, so the new_col = 0.

So the expected output is:

| group 1 | group 2 | cond 1 | point | total_capacity | new_c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 0 | 0.3 | 2 | 0. |
| A | 1 | 1 | 0.5 | 2 | 0. |
| A | 1 | 0 | 0.8 | 2 | 0. |
| A | 1 | 0 | 0.2 | 2 | 0. |
| A | 1 | 0 | 0.4 | 2 | 0. |
| B | 2 | 0 | 0.6 | 4 | 0. |
| B | 2 | 0 | 0.3 | 4 | 0. |
| B | 2 | 1 | 0.1 | 4 | 1. |
| B | 2 | 0 | 0.4 | 4 | 0. |
| B | 3 | 0 | 0.5 | 4 | 0. |
| B | 3 | 0 | 0.2 | 4 | 0. |

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: can you add an example of your expected output?

Comment: yes sure, apologies couldn't properly add in the question. The new col should have the following values: 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0. We have 1 in the second group because, the cumulative condition also gets satisfied there

Comment: I'm not getting this part: _But when we include the cumulative sum and the reset count, new_col will 0, because 0.5 + 0.8 is 1.3, so 0.5 = reset_count = 1, 0.8+0.2 = 1, reset_count =2 and 0.4 reset_count =3, finally, the condition reset_count 3 < 2 is not true, so the new_col = 0._

I think it should be ... *0.5+0.8=1.3 -> reset_count=1 ; 0.2+0.4 = 0.6 (last row for group A) -> reset_count =2 -> reset_count = total_capacity ; new_col = 1*

What am I missing?

Comment: when we sum 0.5+0.8 it exceeds 1.1 so, it should reset at 0.5 = reset_count = 1, then , again cumulative sum starts from 3rd row, 0.8 + 0.2 +0.4 = 1.4 so the reset_count = 2 at 4th row 0.2. Then again last value of group 0.4. so in the first group A and 1, when cond 1 = 1- we have done the cumulative sum 3 times. which is more than total_capacity. so the new col cannot be 1. But on the other hand, in the next group B-2 combination, when cond 1 =1, we start summing up 0.1 +0.4 = 0.5 < total capacity 4. So we populate new_column as 1 when cond 1 = 1

Answer (score 1):

I've got the expected result doing this:

```
df['new_c'] = 0
for index, row in df[df["cond 1"] == 1].iterrows():
    df_group = df[(df["group 1"] == row["group 1"]) & (df["group 2"] == row["group 2"])]
    df_selected = df_group.loc[row.name:]
    cum_sum = 0
    reset_count = 0
    for _, selected_row in df_selected.iterrows():
        cum_sum += selected_row['point']
        if cum_sum >= 1.1:
            reset_count += 1
            cum_sum = selected_row['point']
        if selected_row.name == df_group.index.max():
            reset_count += 1
            
    if reset_count <= row['total_capacity']:
        df.at[index, 'new_c'] = 1
```

I've tested it printing the cumsum and reset_count for debugging and it works as expected in your explanation.